# use non-equi join to define set of data in one data frame that are within a certain range from another data frame in R

Tags: r, range, extract, non-equi-join

Im new to R and I have a very difficult task want to complete.

I have two set of data frame. DF1 consists of 810 observations with 4 variables, DF2 consists of 1707 observations with 51 variables.
Here is some example of

DF1:

Chr POS Range_Plus_10 Range_Minus_10

2 47403201      47403211       47403191

2 47403202      47403212       47403192

2 47403210      47403220       47403200

2 47403210      47403220       47403200

2 47403210      47403220       47403200

2 47403211      47403221       47403201

DF2:

Chromosome Position
2 47630258
2 47630263
2 47630263
2 47630269
2 47630271
2 47630275
Note: not all variables are shown for df2, I am not interested in other variables, but it would be good to keep other variables in the output data.

what I want is to filter through all the positions in df2 to see if any of these positions lies within the range of df1 (within the Range_Plus_10 and Range_Minus_10 for every single row).
For example, first position in df2 is 47630258 and I want to know whether this 47630258 lies within any of the range_plus_10 and Range_Minus_10 in df1 in any row, so I want R to give me an output column with all possible positions in df2 that could corresponds to every rows in df1 range.

I tried to use non equi join but I keep getting some errors and not sure where it got wrong.
Could someone provide a code to obtain the data I want, and secondly tell me why my errors occur.

here is the script I've used:

```
library (data.table)
```

`result <- df2[df1, . ("Chromosome", "Position"), on = .(Position < Range_Plus_10, Position >Range_Minus_10), by = .EACHI]`

But I keep getting an error message:
Error in `[.data.frame`(df2, df1, .("Chr", "Position", ...), on = .(Position <  :
unused arguments (on = .(Position < Range_Plus_10, Position > Range_Minus_10), by = .EACHI)

Sorry for my formatting

Comment: Is `df1` and `df2` data.table? What does `class(df2)` return?

Comment: yes so they were from csv files, which I have loaded as data table, then converted to data frame1 and data frame2.

Comment: sorry Im new to R, what do you mean by class(df2) return?